# Setcookie works in other browsers but not in Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, cookies

I got it working on others but on (Firefox the most important one), it doesn't work. What's wrong in my code ? or what's wrong with Firefox :)

```
if($_COOKIE['ea1']){
die ("cookies set");
} else {
setcookie('ea1',1,time()+24*60*60);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if($_COOKIE['ea1']){
die ("cookies set");
} else {
setcookie('ea1',1,time()+24*60*60,'/','example.com');
}
```

you might also think of clearing your browsers cookies before

EDIT: if you are on localhost you might have to use

```
setcookie('ea1',1,time()+24*60*60,'/',false);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

1. //Set_Cookie('mycookie', 'visited 9 times', 30, '/', '', '');
   function Set_Cookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
       if (!hasKey()) {
           return;
       }

   ```
   var today = new Date();
   today.setTime(today.getTime());
   if (expires) {
       expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
   }
   var expires_date = new Date(today.getTime() + (expires));

   document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
       ((expires) ? ";expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() : "") +
       ((path) ? ";path=" + path : "") +
       ((domain) ? ";domain=" + domain : "") +
       ((secure) ? ";secure" : ""); }
   ```

   function Get_Cookie(check_name) {
       var a_all_cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
       var a_temp_cookie = '';
       var cookie_name = '';
       var cookie_value = '';
       var b_cookie_found = false;

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < a_all_cookies.length; i++) {
       a_temp_cookie = a_all_cookies[i].split('=');

       cookie_name = a_temp_cookie[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

       if (cookie_name == check_name) {
           b_cookie_found = true;
           if (a_temp_cookie.length > 1) {
               cookie_value = unescape(a_temp_cookie[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
           }
           return cookie_value;
           break;
       }
       a_temp_cookie = null;
       cookie_name = '';
   }
   if (!b_cookie_found) {
       return null;
   } }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues sometimes with cookies and redirects.  Make sure you're setting your Location header BEFORE you're Set-Cookie header for maximum browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem, this worked for me:

Set a cookie on localhost, use `false`

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", false);
```

To delete same cookie use negative time

```
setcookie("TestCookie", '', time()-3600, "/", false);
```